# Confused on file and directory permissions for Samba shares

Tags: permissions, samba, umask

I've been searching for while to try to understand the following mask/mode fields for creating files/folders in Samba shares:

```
create mask
force create mode
directory mask
force directory mode
```

But I've failed... I'm looking into changing the files/folders to specific permissions (when files/folders are created on the Samba shares) but the combination of the mask and mode is complicating things.

Here's what I'm after for **file and directory *creation* permissions**:

**File:** `-rw-rw-r--` `(664)`

**Directory:** `drwxrwxr-x` `(775)`

What do I have to set on the above 4 Samba configuration fields to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't quite understand how they work but after testing a little bit more I found that the following actually worked for what I wanted:

```
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
```

I'll us this for now... Let me know if you have an alternative that makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

First set unix permission for users,better if use acl
for example you want to share pubblica with permission of 770
only for group "domain users"

in smb.conf

```
[Pubblica]
   comment = Dir pubblica
   browseable = yes
   public = yes
   path = /var/pubblica
   writable = yes
   force create mode = 0660
   force directory mode = 0770
   valid users = @"Domain Users"
```

on linux side

```
chmod 770 /var/pubblica
setfacl  -m g:"domain users":rwx /var/pubblica
setfacl  -d -m o:---  /var/pubblica
```

The first acl give to domain users the 777 permission
the second deny access read and write to others.

In this case we had a var/pubblica dir only for domain users
adapt this to your situation

Comment: This doesn't answer the question _"What do I have to set on the above 4 Samba configuration fields to achieve this?"_.

Comment: Read the answer,for the permission you will set the unix side with acl and the windows side using smb.conf

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Ok sorry probably i don't understand your question

Comment: I edited the question to try and clarify.